# RoR: form_for action button doesn't respond

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I'm coding the project from *Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example* and am having trouble with the following and unfollowing features.

I have a piece of HTML in one of my pages that looks like this:

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.build(:followed_id => @user.id),
             :remote => true do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Follow" %></div>
<% end %>
```

My RelationshipsController has a create method, but it is never called. The same applies to my 'unfollow' html and corresponding destroy method. Is there something I need to add to my project to let Rails know that the relationships.build method should call the create method, or is that automatic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the log showing that it is receiving the request? What are the `javascript_include_tag` calls? Have you included `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>`  ?

Comment: The log doesn't show that it is receiving the request, but I have included the other two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

> RelationshipsController has a create method

```
current_user.relationships.build()
```

Is it create or build?

Show us the controller code. Since you use "remote=> true" you probably need to change the "respond_to" code in there and create a js.erb file.